# RxJava How to throw error from Observable.fromCallable(()

Tags: rx-java, observable, throwable

If I use:

class 1:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> awsS3.beginUpload(data.bmpPath));
```

class2:

```
public  String beginUpload(String filePath) {
   //what if I want to throw error here?
}
```

how can I throw an Observable error in the beginUpload() method?

Answer (score 3):

`fromCallable` takes a `Callable` which has a `call() throws Exception` method, therefore, you can declare your method as `throws X` where X is the exception type you need to throw:

```
public  String beginUpload(String filePath) throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Comment: so it will then be caught in Observable.subscribe (     @Override
                    public final void onError(Throwable e)  )  ?

Comment: `fromCallable` catches it and calls `onError()` on the `Subscriber`.